# How can I take a sample still image from two pictureBoxes in fullscreen every X seconds?

Tags: c#

The code:

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = (this.ClientSize.Width -
    this.splitContainer1.SplitterWidth) / 2;
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"d:\gifs\RadarGifAnimatoion.gif");//pb1.Image;
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"d:\gifs\SatelliteGifAnimatoion.gif");//pb2.Image;
timer1.Interval = animationSpeed;
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

And I have a timer tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

In this example the timer interval is 80ms.
So inside the timer1 tick event I want each 80ms to take a snapshot or a screenshot of both pictureBoxes and save this shot to the hard disk.

So in the end I will have on the hard disk for example 5 images of the two pictureBoxes .
So if I edit each image of the 5 on the hard disk I will see the two pictureBoxes images.

How can I do it in the timer1 tick event ?

[image]

The update code in the timer1 tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var still = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
            {
                this.DrawToBitmap(still, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), still.Size));
                still.Save(String.Format(@"d:\GifForAnimation\still_{0}.gif", sequence++), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                if (sequence == 5)
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                }
            }

        }
```

I set the timer1 interval in the constructor to the same speed of the animation when created it. The animation speed is 80ms so the timer1 is set to 80ms too.

And still instead of taking each 80ms an image of the pictureBoxes it's taking or saving the same image.
5 images that are the same.

Comment: If you are trying to extract the frames of the Gif's you should use an API instead of doing this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712708/how-to-split-an-animated-gif-in-net

Comment: No I have two animated gifs already. This two gif files names are animated already and I have a small wrapper I did of the program UnfreeZ from c++ to c# that I can create animated gif files with. What I want to do now is to create one animated gif file wich will contain inside the two animated files animations ! That's why now that im showing in the pictureBoxes in fullscreen the two animations from the files each in each pictureBox I want to take a screenshots of the two pictureBoxes every 80ms and then create a new animated gif of this screenshots. I don't need to extract.

Comment: I don't need to extract I need to save each 80ms the screenshot of the two pictureBoxes to the hard disk.

Comment: So in the end on the hard disk I will have 5 images of the pictureBoxes togeather so each image on the hard disk will contain the two pictureBoxes. I need to save create a screenshot of the two pictureBoxes each 80ms not to extract frames.

Comment: Just updated my question edited it with an image example of how the screenshots I want to take each 80ms should looks like. That's what I mean. So in the end of the process I will have for example 5 images on the hard disk each image will looks like this one in my question.

Comment: The one in my question I took using the PrtScn button on the keyboards. But I need do it in the run time code in the timer tick event somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a screenshot you could try this code:

```
int sequence = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var still = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height))
    {
        form.DrawToBitmap(still, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), still.Size));
        still.Save(String.Format(@"c:\still_{0}.gif", sequence++), ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
}
```

Instead of the form you could refer to any container that contains both images.

**EDIT**

This screenshot does not include the start menu, just the container of the two image controls.

**EDIT2**

Rendering the UI to a bitmap like this might not animate the GIF's because the bitmap has no awareness of the animations. You will also get into a race condition: updating the GIF's and making the screenshots within a specific time period in the right order.

I'd use videos capturing software to record a video and select the frames I needed. That is much easier than trying to solve this issue and potential race condition

Comment: Emo tried your code: instead: form.Width and form.Height I did: this.Width and this.Height then also inside the using...I changed it noth to this.Width and this.Height now the line : form.DrawToBitmap(still, still.Size); give me error so I changed form to this again. Now its giving me an error on this line: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.DrawToBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing.Rectangle)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: The error on the DrawToBitmap also say: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Size' to 'System.Drawing.Rectangle'

Comment: Emo tried your code in the timer tick event but the 5 images on hard disk are all the same one instead of be 5 different. I just updated my question now with the code how im using it in the timer.

Comment: I am afraid the images are re-rendered using DrawToBitmap so they start at the first frame of the GIF animation. I'd use videos capturing software to record a video and select the frames I needed. That is much easier than trying to solve this issue and potential race condition.