# MonoMac System.Drawing.Image.GetPropertyItem(0x5100)

Tags: c#, image, mono, gdi, system.drawing

Recently, I was trying to answer another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722787/c-sharp-drawing-imaging-dropping-gif-frames-if-they-are-identical/17723642#17723642) about loading the frames (Bitmap and duration) of animated `GIFs`. The code can be found on [pastenbin](http://pastebin.com/Y6iUGDX9).

While doing additional tests on this code before moving it into my dev library, I noticed that there is a problem with this line of code:

```
//Get the times stored in the gif
//PropertyTagFrameDelay ((PROPID) 0x5100) comes from gdiplusimaging.h
//More info on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534416(v=vs.85).aspx
var times = img.GetPropertyItem(0x5100).Value;
```

When running this on Windows .Net using this ([example GIF](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Triple-Spiral-Labyrinth-animated.gif)), the array is of the same size as the amount of frames in the animated `GIF` and filled with the durations of the frames. In this case a byte[20] which converts to (BitConverter.ToInt32()) **5** durations:

```
[75,0,0,0,125,0,0,0,125,0,0,0,125,0,0,0,250,0,0,0]
```

On MonoMac however, this line of code for the same example GIF  returns a `byte[4]` which converts to only one duration (the first):

```
[75,0,0,0]
```

I tested this for 10 different `GIF's` and the result is always the same. On Windows all durations are in the byte[], while MonoMac only lists the first duration:

```
[x,0,0,0]
[75,0,0,0]
[50,0,0,0]
[125,0,0,0]
```

Looking at the Mono `System.Drawing.Image` [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Image.cs), the length seem to be set in this method, which is a [GDI](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/gdipFunctions.cs) wrapper:

```
status = GDIPlus.GdipGetPropertyItemSize (nativeObject, propid,out propSize);
```

However, I don't really see any problems, not with the source as with my implementation. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: I believe you will find the answer in the Mono GDI Plus implementation. I took a look at it, but I do not have the expertise on the gif codec to decipher what is going on. Following is some of what I found. [Image.FromFile](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Image.cs) calls into [libgdiplus](https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/tree/master/src). Inside libgdiplus are functions to load images. The function `gdip_load_gif_image` inside of file [gifcodec.c](https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/blob/master/src/gifcodec.c) loads gif images.

Comment: You will need to look into what happens inside of `gdip_load_gif_image`. As I mentioned, that is where the image is loaded/ decoded and where I would guess the bug is. I do not have the gif expertise to figure out what is going on. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [look into libgdiplus](https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/blob/master/src/image.c#L2038) you will see that the properties are always read from the active bitmap:

```
if (gdip_bitmapdata_property_find_id(image->active_bitmap, propID, &index) != Ok) {
```

You can set the active bitmap by calling [Image.SelectActiveFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.selectactiveframe.aspx) and then mono will return the correct durations, one by one. Since this is an incompatibility with windows, I'd call it a mono bug. As a simple workaround, you can of course just check the array length and handle both cases. This will be better than a check for mono, because if mono gets fixed this will continue to work.

Comment: This works great and thanks for the cross-platform compatibility suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong in the mono source either.  It would have been helpful if you would have posted one of the sample images you tried.  One quirk about the GIF image format is that the Graphics Control Extension block that contains the frame time is *optional* and may be omitted before an image descriptor.  Non-zero odds therefore that you have GIF files that just have one GCE that applies to all the frames, you are supposed to apply the same frame time to every frame.

Do note that you didn't get 4 values, the frame time is encoded as a 32-bit value and you are seeing the little endian encoding for it in a byte[].  You should use BitConverter.ToInt32(), as you correctly did in your sample code.

I therefore think you should probably use this instead:

```
//convert 4 bit value to integer
var duration = BitConverter.ToInt32(times, 4*i % times.Length);
```

Do note that there's another nasty implementation detail about GIF frames, frames #2 and up do not have to be the same size as the frame #1.  And each frame has a metadata field that describes what should be done with the previous frame to merge it with the next one.  There are no property IDs that I know of to obtain the frame offset, size and undraw method for each frame.  I think you need to render each frame into a bitmap yourself to get a proper sequence of images.  Very ugly details, GIF needs to die.

Comment: Nasty details indeed. This is [one of the GIFS](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Triple-Spiral-Labyrinth-animated.gif) I tried that works on Windows but not on MonoMac with the [code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Y6iUGDX9). For this GIF, the `times` var is 
`byte[20]={75,0,0,0,125,0,0,0,125,0,0,0,125,0,0,0,250,0,0,0}` on Windows but 
`byte[4]={75,0,0,0}` on MonoMac. 

As mentioned earlier, all GIFs I tried work on Windows so I guess this is not one of the quirks of GIF but rather a problem with Mono?

Comment: Yes, can't sweep that under a floor mat.